# Spring configuration: TypeMismatchException

Tags: spring, config, javabeans

Using Spring 3.2 and Quartz 1.8. I've configured a `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean` as follows:

```
<bean id="a" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.MyJob" />        
    ...           
</bean>
```

I'd like to change this configuration so that the jobClass refers to a bean instance so that I can set some properties on the bean:

```
<bean id="b" class"com.MyJob">
   <constructor-arg name="arg" value="1"/> 
</bean>
<bean id="a" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
   <property name="jobClass" ref="b" />        
    ...           
</bean>
```

When launching the app with this config, I get

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.MyJob' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'jobClass'.
```

Why is that? I assume it's because the jobClass property requires a class and not an instance, so how do I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. You can inject some properties into the jobDataAsMap, which in turn injects them into setters into you jobClass (or can be retrieved programmatically from the JobExecutionContext.jobDetail in your jobClass).

```
<bean id="a" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.MyJob" />        
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="propA" value="10" />
            <entry key="propB" value="3" />              
           </map>
    </property>       
</bean>
```